# Replacement of the dot function from plyr

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

How can I transform a vector of groups specified using the `plyr` function `.` such as `.(group, sex)` into a vector of characters like this `c("group", "sex")`.

We used the plyr approach to specify the groups in an older version of our R package. In the new version we want the user to specify the groups using a vector of strings, but we do not want to break previous code that used the dot approach.

Example of the old function:

```
library(plyr)

my_function_old <- function(df, grouping) {
  ddply(df, grouping, summarize,
        m = mean(mpg))
}

my_function_old(mtcars, .(cyl, vs))
```

Example of the new function:

```
library(dplyr)

my_function_new <- function(df, grouping) {
  df %>% 
    group_by(!!!syms(grouping)) %>% 
    summarise(m = mean(mpg))
}

my_function_new(mtcars, c("cyl", "vs"))
```

In the new function the grouping should be specified using a vector of strings. I would like to check whether the user is using the old dot notation in the new function and in that case to transform the grouping variables specified with the dot to a vector of strings.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Using `enexpr`

```
library(dplyr)

my_function <- function(df, grouping) {
  grouping <- as.character(enexpr(grouping))[-1]
  
  df %>% 
    group_by(!!!syms(grouping)) %>% 
    summarise(m = mean(mpg))
}

my_function(mtcars, c("cyl", "vs")) # this works
my_function(mtcars, .(cyl, vs)) # this also works
```